# Actualizar con un trigger un campo de la misma tablaa

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

```
delimiter //
create trigger Subtotal 
after insert on detalle_pedido
for each row  
begin
declare subtotal int;
set subtotal= (select sum(Cantidad*Precio) from detalle_pedido join producto on  Producto=ID_Producto  where Producto = ID_Producto and  ID_Detalle_Pedido=ID_Detalle_Pedido);
update detalle_pedido
set SubTotal = subtotal where ID_Detalle_Pedido=ID_Detalle_Pedido;
end//
```

Comment: lo que quiero es que despues de insertar el detalle del pedido me actualise el subtotal haciendo la multiplicacion Cantidad quee esta en detalle pedido y el precio esta en la tabla producto lo que quiero es que se multiplique y me actualizee l campo subtotal

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. El comentario debería de estar en la pregunta. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

El disparador que estás buscando podría ser:

```
CREATE TRIGGER detalle_pedido_before_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON detalle_pedido
  FOR EACH ROW
  set NEW.Subtotal = NEW.Cantidad * (
    SELECT Precio FROM producto
      WHERE ID_Producto = NEW.Producto                                    
  );
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE producto(
  ID_Producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Producto varchar(31),
  Precio float
  );
CREATE TABLE detalle_pedido(
  ID_Detalle_Pedido int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  SubTotal float,
  Producto int,
  Cantidad float,
  FOREIGN KEY(Producto) REFERENCES producto(ID_Producto)
  );
INSERT INTO producto (Producto, Precio) VALUES
  ('Naranjas',100),('Manzanas',200);
```

Al insertar:

```
INSERT INTO detalle_pedido (Producto, Cantidad)
  VALUES (1,5);
```

Obtendrías:

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID_Detalle_Pedido | SubTotal | Producto | Cantidad |
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|                 3 |      500 |        1 |        5 |
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Espero que fuera lo que estabas buscando. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta de la forma que te resulte más útil.

Comment: gracias por ayudame

Comment: Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)